# I want to give serial no in my Query according to Group

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

As per my below query it print group by data , but I want to give seq serial no per group like for first group  1 , 2 , 3 and then next group again 1, 2 , 3.

How can I write it for this query?

```
select tour_no, version_no ,itinerary_detail_no 
from  itinerary_detail 
group by tour_no, version_no, itinerary_detail_no 
order by  count(*) desc
```

Comment: Please add input and expected output

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
select tour_no, version_no ,itinerary_detail_no, row_number () over 
(partition by version_no order by itinerary_detail_no ) seq_no
from  itinerary_detail 
group by tour_no, version_no, itinerary_detail_no ;
```

Comment: Dear Mansi this code is showing Seq No but like first group having 5 data it show 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 as seq no and then second group seq no show 6 which i donot want i want this start again 1 , 2 like

Comment: provide sample date @AmarDas

Comment: @AmarDas ,please provide with proper input and output data if you want us to help on your problem.  as per all the answers below, you can try out analytical functions row_number or Rank() for this problem.

Comment: Hi as you give it is working fine but you hard coded 5 values only i want a general query where this result shown

Comment: it will work same when you use with your table, this is just sample data you provided,rather than creating table I put it with WITH clause

Comment: sorry but not getting can you give me proper query

Comment: select tour_no, version_no ,itinerary_detail_no, row_number () over 
(partition by version_no order by itinerary_detail_no ) seq_no
from  itinerary_detail 
group by tour_no, version_no, itinerary_detail_no ;

Comment: No still have same issue i mean it show seq one by one but my req is as per group means in next group seq no should start with 1 again which is not shown

Comment: This is my result, pretty much same with your result.
TOUR_NO VERSION_NO ITINERARY_DETAIL_NO SEQ_NO
JAA0000197 1 17037249 1
JAA0000197 1 17037250 2
JAA0000197 2 17037249 1
JAA0000197 2 17037250 2
JAA0000197 2 17037251 3

provide proper input/ output and create/insert scripts to help you out on this.

Comment: Yes i as per your With Clause this is what exactly i want but as your query which you given with out with cluase when i run in my Database it is not given same result

Comment: Hi is there any more solution

Comment: i solve this issue now by using your query but i have modified some line only thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can produce a serial number for each row, as shown below:

```
select
  tour_no, version_no, itinerary_detail_no,
  row_number()
    over(order by cnt desc, tour_no, version_no, itinerary_detail_no) as rn
from (
  select tour_no, version_no, itinerary_detail_no, count(*) as cnt
  from itinerary_detail 
  group by tour_no, version_no, itinerary_detail_no
) x
order by cnt desc, tour_no, version_no, itinerary_detail_no
```

Result:

```
TOUR_NO  VERSION_NO  ITINERARY_DETAIL_NO  RN
-------  ----------  -------------------  --
1                17                    5   1
1                10                    5   2
2                10                    5   3 
3                10                    5   4
```

For reference, the data script for this test is:

```
create table itinerary_detail (
  tour_no number(6),
  version_no number(6),
  itinerary_detail_no number(6)
);

insert into itinerary_detail (tour_no, version_no, itinerary_detail_no) values (1, 10, 5);
insert into itinerary_detail (tour_no, version_no, itinerary_detail_no) values (1, 10, 5);
insert into itinerary_detail (tour_no, version_no, itinerary_detail_no) values (1, 17, 5);
insert into itinerary_detail (tour_no, version_no, itinerary_detail_no) values (1, 17, 5);
insert into itinerary_detail (tour_no, version_no, itinerary_detail_no) values (1, 17, 5);
insert into itinerary_detail (tour_no, version_no, itinerary_detail_no) values (2, 10, 5);
insert into itinerary_detail (tour_no, version_no, itinerary_detail_no) values (3, 10, 5);
```

**Tour_No       Ver_No  IT_No       Seq_No
JAA0000197     01         17037249           1
JAA0000197     01         17037250           2
JAA0000197     02         17037249           1
JAA0000197     02        17037250            2
JAA0000197     02        17037251            3

here group by is (Tour_No,ver_No) so this above data I want 
like every group to start from 1 and than 2, and go on, and for next group same again

Comment: @AmarDas Please add the sample data and expected result to the question. I can't read that comment well.

Comment: i have added my data on your query

Answer (score 0):

You need `rank()`

```
     SELECT tour_no, version_no ,itinerary_detail_no,
   RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY tour_no, version_no ,itinerary_detail_no,count(*) as 
     count_of_records ORDER BY count_of_records DESC ) AS "Rank"
     FROM   Employees group by  tour_no, version_no ,itinerary_detail_no;
```

Comment: it give me below error  ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 28 Column: 80

Comment: Check its syntax you may have forgot to add right parenthesis somewhere  )

Comment: No still have same issue

Comment: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 83 Column: 80

Comment: Did the above answer helped you to solve your query?

Comment: No but i got another way to get this